# iOS: get available locales in my project

Tags: ios, localization, localizable.strings

I created several .strings files for my app's localization. Each one is corresponding to a locale. Now I  want to get a list of all available locale in my app. Is there any function to help me do that??

E.g. if my app just supports English, Chinese, French
the function can return [en, zh, fr]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

swift:

```
var availableLanguages = NSBundle.mainBundle().localizations as [String]
```

objc:

```
NSArray *availableLanguages = [[NSBundle mainBundle] localizations];
```